# using MVC URL.actionlink in callback of jquery ajax function

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a URL.ActionLink into my callback of my jquery ajax function.  The callback adds some text to a div on the page and I want that text to have a link in it.  I want the link to go in the success function.  This code is in my view.  I need to add "`<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Cart")">cart</a>`" around my "cart" text in the success function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("_AddToCart", "Cart")',
    data: {
        id: id,
        qty: quantity
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $("#summary").html(response);
        if (quantity == 1) {
            $("#note" + id).html("1 item added to cart!");
        }
        else {
            $("#note" + id).html(quantity + " items added to cart!");
        }
        $("#note" + id).stop();
        $("#note" + id).fadeIn().delay(1500).fadeOut('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTotal", "Cart")',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (count) {
                $("#itemCount" + id).html(count + " of these in your cart");
            }
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("An Error has occured");
    }
});
```

Comment: And what part doens't work?

Comment: is this in a javascript file or a view?

Comment: added clarifying details

Comment: Look at/post resulting HTML/JS (view source in browser) too.

Comment: Well, I know how to manually create the link.  But that is not very robust obviously.  I want to leverage the dynamic abilities of MVC to create the link using url.action.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Simply saying you are trying to do something doesn't really tell us much.  if i had to hazard a guess what your problem is it is that you probably have the above code in a .js file, and neither of the action links are working because of this, but without further details I have no idea if I am correct or not

Answer (score 0):

Try putting double quotes around your Url.Action call:

```
url: "@Url.Action("GetItemTotal", "Cart")"
```

Also make sure this is in a View and not a JS file.